# .htaccess remove parameters in url redirect

Tags: .htaccess

In my .htaccess file I have:

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} /home/?acc=home&ln=0
RedirectMatch (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/es/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{query_string} /home/?acc=home&ln=1
RedirectMatch (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/fr/? [R=301,L]
```

My idea is:

Source: `www.domain.com/home/?acc=home&ln=0`
Destination: `www.newdomain.com/es/`

Source: `www.domain.com/home/?acc=home&ln=1`
Destination: `www.newdomain.com/fr/`

But my result is:
`www.newdomain.com/es/?`
`www.newdomain.com/fr/?`

How I can remove the "?" ?

Comment: Actually... can you mix things in `mod_rewrite` with `mod_redirect`?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} /home/?acc=home&ln=1
RedirectMatch (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/fr/? <- surely it's the question mark on the end of your redirect?
```

Comment: If I remove the question mark, the result is: www.newdomain.com/fr/?acc=home&ln=0